# Celery Pickiling error with dynamic models

Tags: celery, django-celery

I'm using celery with a function which writes data into a database table.

This table doesn't have a related model inside models.py because I create it dynamically using [django-mutant](https://github.com/charettes/django-mutant).

When I run my task, it correctly writes on my dynamic table, but at the very end of the task I get the following error:

```
[2013-07-10 09:10:45,707: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Task topology_py.Functions.Functions.objectAggregate[aff70510-1e93-4610-b08c-c3675c92afe9] INTERNAL ERROR: PicklingError("Can't pickle <class 'mutant.apps.tss.models.1_tmp'>: import of module mutant.apps.tss.models failed",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/task/trace.py", line 261, in trace_task
for callback in task_request.callbacks or []]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 197, in apply_async
return self._apply_async(args, kwargs, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 472, in apply_async
**options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 249, in publish_task
**kwargs
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 157, in publish
compression, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 233, in _prepare
body) = encode(body, serializer=serializer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 170, in encode
payload = encoder(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 356, in dumps
return dumper(obj, protocol=pickle_protocol)
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'mutant.apps.tss.models.1_tmp'>: import of module mutant.apps.tss.models failed
```

The model that celery is searching for, `1_tmp` is not stored in my app, named *tss*, but inside *mutant* app tables.

My problem is that if I chain this function as a subtask to another subtask, celery terminates with this error at the end of the first one!

Is there a way to tell celery where to find this model or anyway to skip this error and go further to next subtasks?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** at the moment I can run even 5 functions in a chain using 5 immutable subtasks. They work correctly and fill correctly the dynamic table, but the first one, and only the first one, continue producing the error described...Can you give me and idea of why only the first one give me the error since that they access the dynamic model in the same identical way?

Comment: So, are you creating this dynamically created related model inside the task?

Comment: No, I create dynamically the model before, and after that I fill it with the task. The celery task does only sql inserts...

Comment: Celery tasks run in a seperate process. If you dynamically created a related model, then start a Celery task, the task won't have this dynamically created related model. Why do you need these dynamically created related models anyway?

Comment: I need them to manage some shapefile ingestion, no other ways found in 2 years of attempts. Ok, but why if celery does not have the model description it can fill the dynamic table correctly?

Comment: I don't know exactly how django-mutant works. Maybe it does really create the table in the database, but maybe the relation isn't set in the task because the mutation hasn't been performed in the task?

Comment: I don't know but I can assure you that the dynamic table is created into the database. I trust my pgadmin ;-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33197/discussion-between-rednaw-and-caneta)

Comment: Celery cannot do much about it, but the generated models may define `__reduce__` to support pickle (e.g. they could be reconstructed by generating the model again)

Comment: Example `def __reduce__(self): return (create_model, (self.arg1, self.arg2, self.arg3))`  See http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__

Comment: The only reference to a `__reduce__()` method is [here](https://github.com/charettes/django-mutant/blob/master/mutant/models/model/__init__.py) at line 106. But it is better ask to django-mutant author for that. Thank you, asksol!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved: it was an issue inside my first function: I was returning an object of the dynamic model at the end of its execution and that made a celery/django-mutant mess.
This object was completely useless and so deleting its return solved the problem.
Thank you everybody.